# ng-click to trigger a function in app.js not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am learning javascript. I want to make a small chat app using angular js.

all of the data will be stored in javascript data structures - arrays, objects and be brought out to the front using angular js and styled with css.

now I have a button in index.html like this

```
<div class="container">
  <button ng-click="createuser"></button>
</div>
```

in my js I have a controller where I am hanging an array called test on angular's $scope

```
$scope.tests = [ {'username': 'I am Joe'}];
```

I am looping through the tests array with ng-repeat in index.html

```
<li ng-repeat="test in tests">
  {{test.username}}
</li>
```

now I have a method on the $scope object

```
$scope.createuser = function createuser() {
    $scope.tests.push({'username': 'Mandy'})
};
```

that takes the array and use the push method (of the array) to push a sample object into the tests

but when I go to index.html and click, its not working because Mandy is not getting added to the loop.

Please note the method should see the $scope.tests because its all under one controller.

Comment: `ng-click="createuser()"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Forgot the `()`

```
ng-click="createuser()"
```